# Page by Page view of .doc,.Pdf files from sdcard in android

Tags: android

I'm doing an android application which needs to read out some .doc,.txt,.pdf,.xps files from sdcard and displayed in page by page manner.(i.e) If the file is something like a eBook.,i want to show its contents page wise.Is it possible in android?If so how could i do that?Thanks